# Thin process duplicates after upstart.conf run

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, thin

I'm trying to run `thin` server in upstart. Here is what my `upstart.conf` file contains:

```
description 'kitfaye'

start on runlevel [12356] stop  on runlevel [!12356]
respawn

script
   exec su -l deploy -c "export RAILS_ENV=production && cd
  /home/deploy/kitfaye && thin start -e production -p 8003 -R config.ru"
end script
```

After I reboot my ubuntu machine I can see in htop 4 processes of `thin`. You can see them in attachment picture. Of course I can't connect to 8003 port. What's going on there?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-jLZf9ippNgYzIwSFZzZUozamM/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you press F5 in htop you see the process hierarchy, which helps explain what you're seeing here.

They're probably ordered like this 586 -> 677 -> 1077 -> 1082.

`586 'su' - spawns
  677  'export ...; cd ...; thin start ...' which spawns
    1077 'thin start ...' which spawns
      1082`

Comment: The problem was in another place, but since this pointed me to the right direction I accepted this answer.

Comment: @MaratAl: A brief explanation of how you solved it would have been appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fairly recent version of Upstart (I think precise is fine) then I would suggest using this config instead:

```
description "kitfaye"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

setuid deploy
chdir /home/deploy/kitfaye
env RAILS_ENV=production

exec thin start -e production -p 8003 -R config.ru"
```